# System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration does not exist

Tags: c#

***how to add System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration ***

Comment: Well, given the error message, it seems to me that you have already figured out how to not add it...  This is part of the Entity Framework 6.0 Beta, isn't it?

Comment: no i want to add assemblye

Comment: I understand that.  Usually, you would add it at the top of your namespace like, `Using System.Windows.Forms;` or add a reference to it in the 'References' of your project.  Do you know how to do either of those?

Comment: but when I come to add a reference about ,Ican't find it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using `Entity Framework`? If so, `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration` is a namespace in `EntityFramework.dll` assembly. So, Add `EntityFramework.dll` reference to your project.

Read [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a202166-c582-4f50-b35d-d4b59b24658d/where-is-systemdataentitymodelconfiguration?forum=adodotnetentityframework).

Comment: thank you yes installing entity framework is required